# Multiple nodes on localhost

Tags: hazelcast

I'm experimenting with HazelMap currently on my dev system, but for some reason only one JVM at a time seems to be willing to speak to the server.

How can I bypass this (ideally through code rather than via the XML).

Comment: please, share your `hazelcast.xml`. Thank you

Comment: @William Dunne, please share some more details. Do you see any error messages ?